# Index rows and columns unexpected results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to understand the following behaviour:

If I have the following data:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |

If I use `=INDEX($A$1:$B$3,,)`
It will correctly show the whole range.

If I use `=INDEX($A$1:$B$3,1,)`
It will correctly show the data for the first row for both columns.

If I use `=INDEX($A$1:$B$3,SEQUENCE(2),)`
I expect it to show the data for the first two rows for both columns. Instead it shows the data of the first two rows, not showing data for the second column.

How come INDEX loses the column reference here?
[image]

Comment: I don't know if it is documented anyplace, but it has been my experience that if you use an array argument for either the `column `or `row` arguments of the `INDEX` function, you  must also use an array for the other argument, else it will default to a single row/column.

Comment: It appears that way. I don't understand the logic though. Also if you use `=INDEX($A$1:$B$3,TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(2)),)` the index result gets transposed, which I would not expect to have effect; I'd only expect that result here: `=TRANSPOSE(INDEX($A$1:$B$3,SEQUENCE(2),))`

Comment: `=INDEX($A$1:$B$3,SEQUENCE(2),SEQUENCE(2))` results in `a` & `2` where I'd expect `$A$1:$B$2` Funny behaviour. `=INDEX($A$1:$B$3,SEQUENCE(2),TRANSPOSE(SEQUENCE(2)))` Shows it correctly.

Comment: I don't believe the use of arrays for the `row` or `column` arguments is even documented by MS.  So we gets what we get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INDEX` reads its parameters as a pair of lists.

For example, using array constants, you can type:

```
=INDEX(A1:B3,{1,3},{1,2})
```

which gives:

```
a    3
```

because Excel reads this as `{1,1}, {3,2}`.

With `SEQUENCE`, an array constant is returned, and so `SEQUENCE(2)` returns `{1;2}`.  When used twice, Excel processes `{1,1};{2,2}`.

You can use `SEQUENCE` to return a vertical array constant, such as

```
SEQUENCE(1,2)
```

which returns `{1,2}`.

Now it works:

```
=INDEX(A1:B3,SEQUENCE(2),SEQUENCE(1,2))
```

Or, using a mix of horizontal and vertical array constants

```
=INDEX(A1:B3,{1;2},{1,2})
```

Ref:

> https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7
>
> Create one and two-dimensional array constants

Comment: Thanks. And because if you gave array arguments in the rows part of the index, the function expects array results on the column part to return values.

Comment: Correct. So Excel reads `{1,{,2}}`  as row 1 **column** 2.

Comment: I've added a bit on the semi-colon.