# FILTER Function with (More than one ARRAYS - Multiple Tables) in One Cell - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, ms-office

I have two different tables (Table1 and Table2 in two different excel sheets. (There could be more than two tables, like 3 or 4)

3rd sheet is for reporting/filtering. Now in third/reporting sheet i want to use Filter function in one cell and want the both tables from both sheets to be spilled out according to given include criteria for both tables

i.e

```
=FILTER(Table1 + Table2
OR
=SORT(FILTER(Table1,inclue,"")+FILTER(Table2,Inclue,"")) << it adds the two results if numbers
```

I hope i am clear in explanation
I am trying to filter both (all) tables showing the result in one go and all i want to do the task is using formula bar, not the VBA. Please help me do that

Comment: Some sample data and the expected result might be helpful.

Comment: Why not use Power Query?

Comment: Here is a UDF that will do what you want, I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655098/replicate-google-sheets-array1-array2-function-in-microsoft-excel-as-user-def/68655804#68655804

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Union" of two tables can be accomplished as

```
=LET(x, table1, y, table2,
rows1, ROWS(x), rows2, ROWS(y),
myrows, SEQUENCE(rows1+rows2),
mycols, SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(x)),
IF(myrows<=rows1, x, INDEX(y, myrows-rows1, mycols)))
```

For 3 tables it can be exetended as

```
=LET(x, Table1, y, Table2, z, Table3,
rows1, ROWS(x), rows2, ROWS(y), rows3, ROWS(z),
myrows, SEQUENCE(rows1+rows2+rows3),
mycols, SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(x)),
IF(myrows<=rows1, x, 
IF(myrows<=(rows1+rows2),INDEX(y, myrows-rows1, mycols), 
INDEX(z, myrows-rows1-rows2, mycols))))
```

For more than three tables, follow the same pattern

Comment: Superb... Great Idea... Thanks Chris Neilsen... It did the job perfectly fine, now i am using x name in LET function as a Filter Function with include arguments instead of tables, and it is performing great. Thanks a bunch man :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LET` to do calculations in each table in one go.

For example:

```
=LET(x, Table1,
y, Table2,
x1, SUM(FILTER(x, range_table1=value)),
y1, SUM(FILTER(y, range_table2=value)),
x1+y1)
```

EDIT as suggested by @Scott Craner: If you want to append the data on top of each other, you can use `SEQUENCE`. EDIT a nice improvement suggested by @chris neilsen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67880473/consolidating-dynamic-named-ranges-from-separate-sheets/67880546#67880546) shows a much cleaner way than I originally had by indexing on both a sequence of rows and columns.

```
=LET(x, table1, y, table2,
rows1, ROWS(x), rows2, ROWS(y),
myrows, SEQUENCE(rows1+rows2),
mycols, SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(x)),
IF(myrows<=rows1, x, INDEX(y, myrows-rows1, mycols)))
```

Comment: Got it, have edited answer to reflect that possibility, thanks

Comment: A somewhat cleaner version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67880546/445425)

Comment: Wow, that is definitely cleaner haha. I was trying to figure out for the longest time why something I couldn't just do ```IF(row_count<rows(x), x, INDEX(y,row_count-rows(x),)```. good to know you need to explicitly state the columns as opposed to leave it open like you can outside of the formula. Thanks

Comment: I had to find that out as well. Nice explanation from JMP here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68235283/index-rows-and-columns-unexpected-results

Comment: This is perfectly working fine but a bit issue i could not understand, if there are more than two tables, like if i add table3... or table4... I edited the question as well to get the best solution for many other people within the same question

Comment: I tried it    '=LET(x, Table1, y, Table2, bc, Table3,
rows1, ROWS(x), rows2, ROWS(y), rows3, ROWS(bc),
myrows, SEQUENCE(rows1+rows2+rows3),
mycols, SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(x)),
IF(myrows<=rows1, x, INDEX(bc, myrows-rows1, mycols)))'     and it did not work