# MS Excel - Join two structured tables

Tags: excel, join, filter, excel-formula

Why does this formula (which works) display BOTH structured tables?

From [Stackoverflow, Chris Neilsen, August 15, 2021](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68790234):

```
=LET(x, table1, y, table2,
rows1, ROWS(x), rows2, ROWS(y),
myrows, SEQUENCE(rows1+rows2),
mycols, SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(x)),
IF(myrows<=rows1, x, INDEX(y, myrows-rows1, mycols)))
```

It is the calculation step in LET():

```
IF(myrows<=rows1, x, INDEX(y, myrows-rows1, mycols))
```

that perplexes me. It appears that EITHER x OR y should result, NOT BOTH.
Thanks.

I carefully worked through the formula and tested parts of the formula independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Figuring Out How a Formula 'Ticks'

- Chris Neilsen's answer was posted before the release of the `VSTACK` function i.e. it can be simplified with:

  ```
  =VSTACK(Table1,Table2)
  ```
- You could rewrite the formula e.g. in the following way:

```
=LET(x, Table1, y, Table2,
rows1, ROWS(x), rows2, ROWS(y),
myrows, SEQUENCE(rows1+rows2),
myrows1, myrows<=rows1,
myrows2, myrows-rows1,
mycols, SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(x)),
result, IF(myrows1, x, INDEX(y, myrows2, mycols)),
result)
```

- Now play with it by replacing the last occurrence of `result` with any of the other variables.

---

- You could also return each of the variables (expressions), or just the unclear ones, in a standalone formula, e.g.:

[image]

Comment: Yea playing with the varaible output is probably the easiest way to explain it. Debugging in Excel... who knew! You're way more generous than me. Nice answer.

Comment: I think I've got it, thank you VB! The IF() function in the calculation part of LET() is actualy sequentially testing values in an array and 'building' the result array from the first table while the test is TRUE and then from the second table when the test becomes FALSE.

Comment: For me, the hardest job with these formulas is explaining how they work. You did a fine job.

Comment: @VBasic2008, honestly you go way above and beyond and you should be leveraging your passion to share information. I think i have your email, I'll ping you if I do.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is based on a sequence of numbers `myRows`. If you display that variable in the let statement, you'll see a list from 1 to what the sum of rows is for BOTH tables.

Thus from the sequence of numeric rows, it's evaluating if the number of rows exceeds the number of rows from the first table. If so, it's returning that first table. If not, it's using index to lookup the respective value in the second table.

It might be clearer if the if statement consistently represented each of the tables in the same way by showing

```
IF(myrows<=rows1,
   INDEX(x, myrows, mycols), 
   INDEX(y, myrows-rows1, mycols))`
```

You could output the various variables by bringing them to the end of the let statement. So here would be the sequence variable `myRows`

```
=LET(x, Table1, y, Table2,
rows1, ROWS(x), rows2, ROWS(y),
myrows, SEQUENCE(rows1+rows2),
mycols, SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(x)),endResult,
IF(myrows<=rows1,  INDEX(x, myrows, mycols), INDEX(y, myrows-rows1, mycols)),myrows)
```

Perhaps this illustration helps:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. A minor point- you stated: "if the number of rows [in x and y] exceeds the number of rows from the first table [x] ... it's returning that first table. If not, it's using index to lookup the respective value in the second table [y]." The IF() appears to be the other way round?

Comment: You should click `accept` on one of these answers...\

Comment: it is not the other way around `sequence_Number_shown_ABOVE <= number_ROws_First_Table then first table`

Comment: The IF() in the rewrite "IF(myrows<=rows1,  INDEX(x, myrows, mycols), INDEX(y, myrows-rows1, mycols)),myrows)" still appears to be returning both the IF()=TRUE AND the IF()=FALSE ??

Comment: Yea an if statement evaluation will tend to return one of those two conditions.... Honestly you've got two incredibly detailed answers. see how VB's answer illustrates how to debug the `Let` formula. Smaller steps and it will make sense (hopefully).

Comment: My bad. Just tested <= with a SEQUENCE() and a numeric value. It appears that a one diemensional sequence has a value of 1.

Comment: My comment above about the 'numeric' value of SEQUENCE() is incorrect. See the solution given by VB below.

Comment: I don't need to see his solution, I already understood the formula. But I'm glad you finally get it and accepted an answer.

Comment: Please, no offence pgSystemTester, my comment about SEQUENCE() and "incorrect" is simply to avoid misleading anyone else reading this thread.